# JSONの配列データのキーの最初の要素だけをJavascriptでalertで表示したい。

Tags: javascript, json

JSONの配列データのキーの最初の要素だけをJavascriptでalertで表示(ABとあを連続でalertで表示)したいのですが下記のソースでは上手くいきません。どのように修正すればよろしいでしょうか。教えていただけませんでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>あいうえお</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

  <body>
   <script>
     var json_data = '{"alfa":["AB","CD","EF","GH"],"hiragana":["あ","い","う","え"]}';
     var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
     for(key in data){
         alert(key[0]);
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`alert(key[0])` を `alert(data[key][0])` に変えてみてください。